# How to share values between different classes in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, sharedpreferences, datastore

Currently I am developing an app where I have to save values of different types of data and access the data from multiple classes when needed. Currently I am using Object(singleton) classes for that. like below:

```kotlin
    object VLineDataHolder {
        private val _logsProgress = MutableStateFlow(0)
        val logsProgress: StateFlow<Int>
            get() = _logsProgress
        fun setLogsProgress(logsProgress: Int) {
            _logsProgress.value = logsProgress
        }
    }
```

I am just not sure If I am doing it in a right way, I don't actually need to persist the data after user exits the app that's why I am not using any DataStore or SharedPreferences here. Can any one explain if it is the good solution or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutuable shared flow inside singleton class and creating a Bus type pattern. Just push the data and observe it from anywhere. As example I want to be noticed whenever use login event happens

```
object EventBusKotlin {

private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<AuthEvents>()
val events = _events.asSharedFlow()

suspend fun publish(event: AuthEvents) {
    _events.emit(event)
}

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
suspend inline fun <reified T> subscribe(crossinline onEvent: (T) -> Unit) {
    events.filterIsInstance<T>()
        .collectLatest { event ->
            coroutineContext.ensureActive()
            onEvent(event)
        }
}

}

sealed class AuthEvents
```

Event model

```
data class LoginEvent(
val userId: String,
val userName: String
):AuthEvents()
```

Observing/Subscribing

```
@Inject
lateinit var eventBus: EventBusKotlin

  //push/publish event
  suspend fun postLoginEvent(loginEvent: LoginEvent) {
     eventBus.publish(loginEvent)
 } 

// subscribing and listening latest event
fun subscribeLoginEvent(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        eventBus.subscribe<AuthEvents> { event ->

            when (event) {
                is LoginEvent -> Log.d(
                    "LoginEventHandler",
                    "${event.userName} logged-in successfully"
                )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I am giving it a try.